# Manual Woocommerce Complete order Emails

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, email, api

How can I send the manual order complete emails to customer menually even after the Order complete emails are turned off in woocommerce>settings? I turned it off because I don't wanna let customer know that their order is done because I'm using [Printful](https://www.printful.com/)(third-party API) which changes the the order status automatically whenever they're done with the product.

Answer (score 0):

Click on the order number of the product. There is **Order Action** section just at the top of right side bar. Click on the dropdown and there you would see "Complete Order" email. 
Thanks;

Comment: I know that already. That option only works if the woocommerce email setting is turned on. But Read properly, It's saying " what if woocommerce>setting>order Complete emails is turned off?